# Nested update query in JSON data type column in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I have added a new  JSON Data type column `(bill_plans)`in my table . Now I want to update the `bill_plans` column like this

```
[{ "cycle": 1, "fee": 1000}, { "cycle": 3, "fee": 2800}, { "cycle": 10, "fee": 10000} ]
```

I was successful in creating the column and I was able to update the bill_plans columns also.

The table contains `bill_cycle` and `fees` also as an existing column so I want to update the `bill_plans` column something like this

```
[{ "cycle": value from the bill_cycle column, "fee": value from the fees column}, { "cycle": value from the bill_cycle column, "fee": value from the fees column}]
```

the simple update query is something like this

```
update  coaching_class_entries set bill_plans =  ('[{"cycle": 1, "fee": 1000}]') where id = 1;
```

But now I am not able to understand how to update the `bill_plans` from the existing columns of the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has predefined functions to perform operations on JSON Arrays and Objects.

You can use the below query to achieve your result.

**Method 1**
Using general syntax

```
UPDATE coaching_class_entries     
  SET bill_plans = '[ {"cycle": 1, "fee": 1000 } ]'
```

In this case you may need to update the values as per the data in columns. You can use `CONCAT` operator to form the json string

```
UPDATE coaching_class_entries     
  SET bill_plans = CONCAT('[{"cycle":"', bill_cycle, '","fee":"', fees, '"}]')
```

**Method 2**
Using JSON Functions

```
UPDATE coaching_class_entries     
  SET bill_plans = JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT("cycle", bill_cycle, "fee", fees))
```

You can refer to the complete docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html